# AngularJS partials with URLs in directives - best practice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

I quite like how angular-ui has created ui-routes, which provides named routes (among other things).

Though likely a simple directive to write—a wrapper for ui-view—I am not sure if it is best practice.

```html
<div ui-view2="foo.html" class="span12">
    Foo haz bar
</div>
```

With the following logic:

```py
if `foo.html` is file: contents of foo.html
elif `$scope.foo.html` exists: contents of `$scope.foo.html`
else: contents defined in view, i.e.: "Foo haz bar"
```

What do you think, would this kind of setup be within the realms of best-practice?

BTW: Is there anything like this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)

```
<div ng-switch="page_name">
  <div ng-switch-when="foo" ng-include="'partials/foo.html.html'">
  <div ng-switch-when="bar" ng-include="'partials/bar.html.html'">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my, not sure how I missed `ng-include`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ng-if` if your logic doesn't fit into a `ng-switch`:

```
<div ng-if="first_condition">something</div>
<div ng-if="!first_condition && second_condition">something else</div>
```